# Проверка хеша временного

Tags: дата, php, md5

Всем добрый вечер/день.

Задача такая: 
Имеются две страницы a1.php и a2.php, a1.php генерирует

```
md5($key.date('ymd H')) // выходит (ключ,150313 22)
```

и редиректит на `a2.php?hash=md5($key.date('ymd H'))`.

На a2.php таким же образом сравнивает хеш.
Получается, если час прошел, то хеш не совпадет.

Проблема:
нужно, чтобы именно прошел час, если время будет 22:59, то хеш проживет 1 минуту.

Есть идеи/решения?

Comment: Дописывайте в начало хэша время создания в том или ином виде. Секретность реального значения обеспечивайте за счет key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запишите хеш в базу. 
После чего

```
$db = query("SELECT * from `table` where `hash` = $hash");
```

И если такая запись есть, то всё замечательно.

Comment: Вряд ли бы стоял вопрос у ТС'а, будь у него доступ к БД...

Comment: @TheDoctor в посте нет ни слова о том, что у ТС нет доступа к бд

Comment: С БД вариант да, но не катит. решил так key.date('ymd ').date('H')-1==hash || key.date('ymd ').date('H')==hash

Comment: Ну а тогда, если dat("H")-1 сгенерит хеш, и в последствии пройдет 2-3-5 часов? 
Пишите в базу время тогда, готовый хеш, и прочие данные, пересобирайте, проверяйте, и всех делов.

Answer (score -1):

Зависимость от `date('H')` - ужасна.
Нужно хотя бы так:

```
<? // File: page1.php
$hash = md5($key . time()); // Генерируем хэш - ключ и timestamp
header('Location: /page2.php?hash=' . $hash);
exit;

<? // File: page2.php
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
if($hash > md5($key . (time() - 3600))){ // Проверяем - MD5 ключа и времени на час меньше
  // Час не истёк
}else{
  // Час истёк
}
```

Правда, тут будет всегда меньше часа, ведь мы генерируем хэш и СРАЗУ перебрасываем на проверку, а перенаправление идёт мгновения, точно меньше часа, так что...
Но можно использовать по-другому, главное, что принцип описан.

Comment: нужно что?

Comment: Секунду, абшибка вышла, сейчас выложу.

Comment: > $hash > md5($key . (time() - 3600))

чтоооооооооооооооооо

то есть md5 от более позднего времени будет гарантированно больше md5 от более раннего?